# Google Analytics: Why don't "Mobile" and "Not Mobile" Segments add up?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two segments based on the radio button in the segment:

1. Mobile
2. Not Mobile.

Why don’t they add up to 100%?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know Mobile traffic is defined by GA as a standard segment, but I don't ever think I've seen "Not Mobile" as a standard that they created. Did you import it from somewhere or did someone else build the segment?

My advice is to copy the "Not Mobile" segment and see exactly how it's defined. My guess is that's the segment where the discrepancy lies.

Also, I believe GA will include sessions with no device data so I wouldn't expect it to be a perfect 100%.